# Finding unique/special pairs in permutations with repetition

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many unique permutations are there If 5 letters are given and need to arrange it in different ways where each pair cannot contain same arrangement?
Permutations with repetitions count but with following restriction.

Example:

Input = A, B, C, D, E

Total permutations with repetition = nΠr = 3125 (where n =5 and r =5)
From this 3125 need to ignore same pair arrangements like follows.

(A, A, A, A, A) == (B, B, B, B, B) == (C, C, C, C, C )== (D, D, D, D, D )== (E, E, E, E, E)
This arrangement is considered as 1 unique pair, not 5 pairs.

Like wise another unique pair would be,

A, B, B, B, B ==
B, A, A, A, A ==
A, C, C, C, C ==
B, C, C, C, C ==
B, D, D, D, D == ...

Appreciate if someone can help me on finding unique permutations like ?

P.S.
For 2 letters: A, B —> { A, A }  { A, B } = 2 unique pairs

For 3 letters A, B, C —> { A, A, A } { A, B, C } { A, A, B } { A, B, B}  {A, B, A } = 3 unique pairs

For 4 letters I manually counted such 15 pairs

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Writing it with country names is unnecessarily messy.  Why not just take $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$?  Much simpler to write.  More importantly...I can't guess what you mean by "pair" and therefore I can't guess which arrangements you wish to identify.  Perhaps it would help if you wrote down all the cases for $\{A,B\}$ and for $\{A,B,C\}$.

Comment: Apologies. I edited the question @lulu

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, these are the [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)...for example, these are the number of possible rhyme schemes for an $n$ line poem.  [here](https://oeis.org/A000110) are the values.  There isn't a convenient closed form.  $B_5=52$.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. This is helpful. I’ll have a look. @lulu